# how to implement screen mirror to my app?

Tags: android, casting

I want to display my app on my SmartTV using the MediaRoute API, but i'm having a hard time learning this thing...

I just want to click a item menu - show the available devices - click one of them - and start casting my app screen to my SmartTV.

Any light?

Comment: Is your TV an Android TV? If not, does it have Chromecast built in? If not, does the manufacturer provide an app that runs on the device that implements a `MediaRouteProvider`?

Comment: It a Smart LG TV, it does have Screenshare built with it, so I only need to implement my app with the MediaRoute API to cast it.

Comment: Well, your "click an item menu - show the available devices" part sounds like a `MediaRouteActionProvider`. Once you get a `MediaRoute`, you can use `Presentation` to display something there. But, again, unless LG offers an app with a `MediaRouteProvider`, your TV will not show up in the `MediaRouteActionProvider`.

Comment: It does because I can cast my Nexus 5 with it Casting feature, also I can use the LG Controller App to use my Smartphones as WiFi Controllers. Is there another way to cast the Presentation aside from using MediaRouteActionProvider? but implementing a simple View button with setRouter or something?

Comment: You can also use `MediaRouteButton`, or query the `MediaRouter` directly for available routes and roll your own UI.

Comment: I see, the problem is, i dont know the procedure, i dont know how to do it or anything, can you provide me a sample?